# WP_UnitTestCase missing?

Tags: testing, unit-tests

I was looking at [tests for wordpress](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tests#trunk/tests/) and some, if not all the classes have WP_UnitTestCase but I cannot find the class, why do I care? I have downloaded [The most up to date version of this from github](https://github.com/kurtpayne/wordpress-unit-tests) which is the same set of tests.

Why does this matter so much? Because when ever I run one of the tests via phpunit filename.php I get the error from php unit stating that its missing WP_UnitTestCase.

So my question is:

Where is this class, why is it missing if it works for the WordPress developers?

Comment: We don't know anything about your process. You did [follow this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Unit_Test) tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class is defined in [`includes/testcase.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tests/trunk/includes/testcase.php). If you checkout the entire repo, you should have it. To check out the entire repo, you should be running something along the lines of:

```
svn co https://unit-tests.svn.wordpress.org/trunk wordpress-tests
```